# DIsplay data from JSON API using vuejs and axios

Tags: javascript, html, json, vuejs2

Below is my JS and HTML code for a Vue.js application I'm building.

The data returns fine but I'm unable to display it on the front.

Any help would be appreciated.

```js
data() {
    return {
      overview: this.getOverview()
    }

  },
  methods: {
    getOverview() {
      return axios.get('http://localhost:8000/v1/overview')
        .then(response => {
          this.results = response.data
          console.log('results data', this.results)
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.log(error);
        })
    }
  }
```

```html
<tr v-for="overview in overview">
  <td>
    {{overview.id}}
  </td>

  <td></td>
  <td class="text-right">
    {{overview.schools}}
  </td>
  <td class="text-right">
    {{overview.primary}}
  </td>
  <td class="text-right">
    {{overview.secondary}}
  </td>

</tr>
```

JSON data

```
{"schools":545,"counsellors":4,"reports":13,"sub_regions":[{"id":1,"name":"Barima-Waini","schools":45,"primary":42,"secondary":3},{"id":2,"name":"Pomeroon-Supenaam","schools":45,"primary":37,"secondary":8},{"id":3,"name":"Essequibo Islands-West Demerara","schools":72,"primary":59,"secondary":13},{"id":4,"name":"Georgetown","schools":69,"primary":54,"secondary":15},{"id":5,"name":"Outside Georgetown","schools":62,"primary":31,"secondary":31},{"id":6,"name":"Mahaica-Berbice","schools":39,"primary":32,"secondary":7},{"id":7,"name":"East Berbice-Corentyne","schools":71,"primary":54,"secondary":17},{"id":8,"name":"Cuyuni-Mazaruni","schools":31,"primary":28,"secondary":3},{"id":9,"name":"Potaro-Siparuni","schools":22,"primary":20,"secondary":2},{"id":10,"name":"Upper Takutu-Upper Essequibo","schools":49,"primary":45,"secondary":4},{"id":11,"name":"Upper Demerara-Upper Berbice","schools":40,"primary":32,"secondary":8}]}
```

Comment: You are missing `return`

Comment: I expect you mean `this.overview = response.data`. Also, you should not name your iterator the same as what you are iterating; `overview in overview` will not work.

Comment: @AluanHaddad please clarify. Should there be another return somewhere in the code? This is my first time with Vue

Comment: Never really used vue myself, but you databindings reference something a property named `overview` which is a `Promise` that will inevitably `resolve` with `undefined` if it resolves.

Comment: That's exactly what happened @AluanHaddad

Comment: I put an answer together, thanks to @Bert for his comments as I'm not sure which pattern is correct. (`return` vs. `assign`) or if Vue allows both.

Comment: Do you want to iterate over `sub_regions`?

Comment: most likely all you are missing is that when you get back the results you need to then store the results in 'overview' becasue that is what Vue is watching in order to know when/how to update teh GUI. I don't see you doing that with your 'results'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: I've never really used Vue myself

The problem is that you are databinding in your view to a view model property named `overview`. The value of `overview` is a `Promise` that will inevitably resolve with undefined, if it resolves, because the final `.then` in your promise chain does not return a value:

```
return axios.get('http://localhost:8000/v1/overview')
  .then(response => {
     this.results = response.data;
     console.log('results data', this.results);
   })
   .catch(function(error) {
     console.log(error);
   });
```

As you can see, we are assigning the response from the API call to a `result` property but that is not what we are binding to. I believe that, as Bert suggests, you need assign to `this.overview` instead of `this.result` if possibly, I would prefer to simply return the resolved value in the promise chain.

Speaking of promise chains, since you are using Vue, you are transpiling, since you are transpiling, you should leverage `async`/`await` for superior readability.

Consider writing code such as

```
async getOverview() {
  try {
    const {data:{json:{sub_regions}}} = await axios.get('http://localhost:8000/v1/overview');
    console.log('results data', sub_regions);
    this.overview = sub_regions;
  }
  catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return [];
  }
}
```

Thank to Bert's link and helpful analysis, I have updated the answer to reflect a common Vue pattern

You will end up with something like this

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      overview: []
    }

  },
  methods: {
    async getOverview() {
      try {
        const {data:{json:{sub_regions}}} = await axios.get('http://localhost:8000/v1/overview');
        console.log('results data', sub_regions);
        this.overview = sub_regions;
      }
      catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return [];
      }
    }
  },
  created(){
    this.getOverview()
  }
})
```

Comment: I hadn't noticed that OP was assigning the results of `getOverview` to `overview`. This is how it would be done typically with Vue: https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/VrBEpJ?editors=1010

Comment: @Bert ah I see. That is more familiar to me actually. I was sort of hoping that maybe Vue supported something more declarative, where the initial value could start out as a promise-in-flight, but that makes sense.

Comment: I recall Angular doing that, but yeah, Vue doesn't at the moment.

Comment: Actually Angular did something evil with $ngResource :D, I think the explicit Vue way is better

Comment: @Bert I updated to reflect the style you of your linked example.

Comment: Your update is most of the way there; the only remaining issue is I don't understand whether OP wants just the `sub_regions` portion of the JSON response (which is what he appears to be iterating in the template) or to store the entire response, and just iterate over the sub regions.

Comment: @Bert store the entire response and iterate over the sub regions